# How to subscribe to angular router navigate method

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-router, dom-manipulation

Hello I'm working on app in which i want to use angular router and after navigate method get some elements from DOM and change their properties. My problem is that when I try to get these elements instantly I'm getting 'Cannot read property 'getElementById' of null' error. Can I somehow wait till page loads ? Code works fine when client is on right url.

This is my code simplyfied:

```
    this.router.navigate(['/' + line.building + '/' + line.level], {relativeTo: this.route});
    const svg = document.getElementsByTagName('svg').namedItem(line.building + line.level +'-svg');
    const rect = svg.getElementById(line.name);
    rect.setAttribute('fill', '#05ff00');
```

Answer (score 0):

window.onload might be what you are looking for, however I don't understand what exactly you are trying to achieve can you please clarify.

Comment: It's kind a what i want to accomplish but it doesn't trigger after router event

Answer (score 0):

you need to subscribe to the router events, then wrap your code inside that event
add at the top:

```
import { Router, NavigationEnd, Event as NavigationEvent } from '@angular/router';
```

then add this within `ngOnInit` hook:

```
this.router.events
      .subscribe(
        (event: NavigationEvent) => {
          if(event instanceof NavigationEnd) {
            const svg = document.getElementsByTagName('svg').namedItem(line.building + line.level +'-svg');
            const rect = svg.getElementById(line.name);
            rect.setAttribute('fill', '#05ff00');
          }
        });
```